# Error in opening the next class

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

```
public class Retrievedata extends AppCompatActivity {
private FirebaseAuth fAuth;
private Firebase mref;
private ArrayList<String> musernames = new ArrayList<>();
private ListView mlistview;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_retrievedata);

    mref=new Firebase("https://rozgarinepal100.firebaseio.com/User");
    mlistview=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listview);
    final ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter= new ArrayAdapter<String> 
 (this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,musernames);
    mlistview.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
    mref.addChildEventListener(new com.firebase.client.ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(com.firebase.client.DataSnapshot 
 dataSnapshot, String s) {
            String value=dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
            musernames.add(value);
            arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildChanged(com.firebase.client.DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildRemoved(com.firebase.client.DataSnapshot 
dataSnapshot) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildMoved(com.firebase.client.DataSnapshot 
 dataSnapshot, String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {

        }
    });

}
}
```

My code is running fine but i get error when opening this class retrieve.data.Emulator stops responding when I wanted to enter to this class where i have created database  to retrieve data from firebase.Here i wanted to retrieve data from my firebase database but  im not able to display anything because the app stops working after entering to this class.

Comment: Is app crashing or giving ANR error? Can you post stack trace from logcat?

Comment: I am getting out of memory -1 something like that in logcat @adityakamble49

Answer (score 1):

You are getting **Firebase Context exception**.

`java.lang.RuntimeException: You need to set the Android context using Firebase.setAndroidContext() before using Firebase`

Depending upon which version you are using you need to pass **context** of **Application** to Firebase like this

```
public class MyApplication extends android.app.Application {

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        //Previous versions of Firebase
        Firebase.setAndroidContext(this);

        //Newer version of Firebase
        if(!FirebaseApp.getApps(this).isEmpty()) {
            FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().setPersistenceEnabled(true);
        }
    }
}
```

And update your Manifest with

```
<application 
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:name=".MyApplication">
...
</application>
```

Comment: @Akash You get this error because you're using a version of Firebase which is over 2 years old. Consider upgrading to a more recent Firebase SDK as shown here: https://firebase.google.com/support/guides/firebase-android#install_the_new_firebase_sdk

Comment: What should be edited in my code then? @FrankvanPuffelen